# Is it good practice to allow table schemas to react to changes coming from the publisher?

Tags: kdb

we have a publisher that amends table schemas quite often.

my manager wants to implement it in such way that when they change the data, our kdb plant reacts to that change and updates the schemas in memory and the hdb so that we won't have to make the changes ourselves. the only change they'd like to do this way is column addition and reordering (no type update or removal)

i think that this is wrong and we shouldn't ever allow someone to amend schemas in our system.

has anyone had to do this before? did it work? any major issues?

Answer (score 3):

Does your manager expect you to be able to react to schema changes intraday? That's another headache because active subscribers (not just the RDB) would have the wrong schema and a single log file would have mixed schema. So any schema change should be done at a coordinated time at restart (e.g. midnight).

Ultimately it sounds like your tickerplant and the upstream data feed needs to share the same schema file. Make it a generic xml/csv file and have both systems share it. It would be simple to write a kdb parser to load in that schema on startup of TP/RDB etc, but as pointed out the HDB dbmaint is the trickier part. You could compare new schema to HDB schema on startup of HDB and infer what the dbmaint changes need to be. Then you'd have to run the dbmaint commands and reload the database when complete.

It's definitely doable but just beware that you're giving automatic ability for schema changes to occur on any arbitrary schema change. Is there going to be sanity checks around the schema change? What if somebody fat-fingers and un-does a change while the HDB is in the middle of dbmainting? Plenty of pitfalls

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you shouldn't update your schema often or at all because it creates all sort of issues you need to handle. Starting from the TP having a new schema so your log file will contain different schemas, same goes for the RDB, this will be problematic at end of day when you save down to disk. You will have to run a dbmaint to bring the schema of the HDB and the RDB in sync.

A more sensible approach is to test your application/upstream until you can agree on a schema that you then keep.

Comment: I know .  it would be an issue when replaying logs, but you can handle that with an updated upd function. 
we do use dev/uat envs to tests changes, but this team wants to have control over the schema update process. 
I disagree with not updating the schema at all. KDB systems are meant to change and grow with the business requirements.